# Question regarding permutations as a product of transpositions

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory

Apologies if the title is not sufficiently descriptive of my following query; I have no ideas on how to better phrase it.

In Fraleigh's $7$th edition book on Abstract Algebra, the following theorem is stated, and then $2$ proofs are provided:

**Theorem:** No permutation in $S_n$ (the symmetric group of $n$ elements), can be expressed as the product of an even number of transpositions and as a product of an odd number of transpositions.

The main idea of the first proof borrows some ideas from linear algebra; in particular, the following $2$ rather well-known properties of the determinant:

$1$. The identity matrix $I_n$ of order $n$ has determinant $1$.

$2$. Interchanging any $2$ rows of a square matrix changes the sign of the determinant.

However, I wonder if using these $2$ properties to argue the validity of the theorem is actually circular logic? Because I have no idea how to prove the above stated $2$ properties without appealing to the Leibniz definition of the determinant:

$$\det(A)= \sum_{\sigma \ \in \ S_n} \text{sgn}(\sigma) \prod_{i=1}^na_{i,\sigma_i}$$

Where $A$ is any $n \times n$ square matrix. However, since the signature of a permutation is equals to $(-1)^m$, where $m$ is the number of transpositions in the decomposition of the permutation, doesn't this (sort of) mandate that the truth of the theorem needs to be established in the first place? Otherwise we could have $\text{sgn} (\sigma)$ equals $1$ and $-1$ at the same time, which does not make sense...

Hence, I would appreciate if anyone is able to prove these $2$ properties of the determinant without appealing to the Leibniz definition?

Comment: There are alternate constructions of the determinant, for instance as a linear alternating homomorphism from $M_n(k)$ to $k$(construction of this can be found at Hoffman and Kunze chapter 5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not necessarily circular, depending on your definition of the sign of a permutation. You could simply define the sign to be $1$ if it has an even number of inversions and $-1$ if it has an odd number, where an inversion is a pair $(i,j)$ where $i<j$ and $\sigma(i)>\sigma(j)$. This does not mention products of transpositions in any way and is definable as an independent invariant. You just want to show that the sign governs the expressibility as a product of an even/odd number of transpositions.

As mentioned in a comment by Ariana, there are is another way of defining the determinant that makes this obvious. The determinant is the unique map from $M_n(k)$ to $k$ that is multilinear in the rows and is alternating such that evaluation on the identity yields $1$. The property of being alternating gives you that exchanging the rows flips the sign.

Comment: Thank you! This was really helpful!

Comment: @ONGSEEHAI Sure, no problem.

Comment: If we use the definition of inversions instead, is it still necessary for us to prove that the number of transpositions and the number of inversions of a permutation share the same parity? Or is it obvious that the number of inversions of a permutation is actually unique?

Comment: @ONGSEEHAI The number of inversions is a measurable quantity, there's no uncertainty about it. It has nothing (on the outset) to do with expressing the permutation as a product of anything.

Comment: Right, this makes sense. Thanks once again!